# Доступ к содержимому iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Есть страница. На ней скрытый iframe, в котором выполняются определенные операции при нажатии кнопки на основной странице. Как получить содержимое фрейма с помощью jquery?
[Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/2tgwdzso/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#hiddenframe').load(function(){
    var iframe = $('#hiddenframe').contents().find("#frame_test_div").html();
    console.log('Ответ '+iframeDocument);

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" name="loadavatar" target="hiddenframe">
<input type=hidden name=MAX_FILE_SIZE value=10485760>
<input id=avatarfile name=filename type=file>
<input type="submit" value="Загрузить" name="Subm" id="uploadButton">
</form>

<iframe id="hiddenframe" name="hiddenframe">
<div id="frame_test_div">фрейм</div>
<?
if (isset($_POST['Subm'])) {
$upload_file = $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"];
list ($validate, $width, $height, $filetype) = validate($upload_file);

if ($validate == 'ok') {

    $filename = new_name($user_id);
    echo 'Файл: '. $filename;
    add_img$upload_file, '../img/temp', $filename, $filetype);

    }
}
?>
</iframe>
```

Comment: что именно находится внутри iframe, и какой у него src установлен, если установлен?

Comment: идет генерация имени файла, загрузка изображения во временную папку. src не установлен. я хочу получить сгенерированное имя файла и статус загрузки.

Comment: _идет генерация имени файла, загрузка изображения во временную папку._ - добавь пример кода. Как ты взаимодействуешь с iframe?

Comment: я не могу получить хотя бы <div id="frame_test_div">фрейм</div>

Comment: Внутри тега iframe размещается сообщение на случай, если браузер его не поддерживает. А если поддерживает, фрейм будет пустым. Зачем вам здесь именно фрейм, чем простого контейнера вроде div мало?

Comment: загрузка изображения без перезагрузки страницы. Я хочу загружать изображения во временную папку, а сгенерированные имена передавать в сессию, для дальнейшей обработки

Comment: Это не объясняет, зачем фрейм. Загрузить изображение без перезагрузки страницы можно, отправив форму на сервер AJAX'ом, а возвращённый сервером в ответе URL скормить в img::src.

Comment: буду разбираться в этом направлении, спасибо